# Tense change in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

Here are the sentences:

1. Fred insisted that he would be driving his own car in the rally.

I initially thought the direct speech would be this:
Fred insisted, “I will drive my own car in the rally.”

But considering the orginal sentence structure, should it be like this?

Fred insisted, "I will be driving my own car in the rally."

1. The officer said, “They look like fugitives from Alcatraz.”

For this sentence, I'm not sure I should use past tense or past perfect.

The officer said that they looked like fugitives from Alcatraz.
The officer said that they had looked like fugitives from Alcatraz.

Which one would be correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out what I quoted from *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan in http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19033/3281. Look for 275.2. Shifting tenses mechanically to report what was said in the past in indirect speech is safe enough in almost all cases.

Comment: [English club](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/reported-speech.htm) has a nice step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 1):

The convention for converting an originally present-tense direct-speech utterance to a past-tense report (indirect speech) is that the present-tense verb in the original is 'backshifted' to past tense.

```
Fred insisted      "I **will**  be driving my car in the rally.  
                         ⇓
Fred insisted that he **would** be driving his car in the rally.
```

As you correctly discern, a reconversion from indirect to direct speech simply undoes this change.

In your *Alcatraz* sentence the tensed verb is simple present *look*; consequently, the indirect-speech version should employ a simple past:

```
The officer said,     “They **look**  like fugitives from Alcatraz.”  
                               ⇓
The officer said that they **looked** like fugitives from Alcatraz.
```

You would employ past perfect only if the original employed present perfect.

```
The officer said,    “They **have** been transported to the hospital”  
                               ⇓
The officer said that they **had**  been transported to the hospital.
```